# Get elements of a sublist in python based on indexes of a different list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists.

I want to get the elements from second list of lists, based on a value from the first list of lists.

I if I have simple lists, everything go smooth, but once I have list of list, I'm missing something at the end.

Here is the code working for two lists (N = names, and V = values):

```
N = ['name 1', 'name 2','name 3','name 4','name 5','name 6','name 7','name 8','name 9','name 10']

V = ['val 1', 'val 2','val 3','val 4','val 5','val 6','val 7','val 8','val 9','val 10']

bool_ls = []
NN = N
for i in NN:
        if i == 'name 5':
            i = 'y'
        else:
            i = 'n'
        bool_ls.append(i)

# GOOD INDEXES = GI

GI = [i for i, x in enumerate(bool_ls) if x == 'y']

# SELECT THE GOOD VALUES = "GV" FROM V

GV = [V[index] for index in GI]
```

if I define a function, works well applied to the two lists:

```
def GV(N,V,name):
    bool_ls = []
    NN = N
    for i in NN:
        if i == name:
            i = 'y'
        else:
            i = 'n'
        bool_ls.append(i)
    GI = [i for i, x in enumerate(bool_ls) if x == 'y']
    GV = [V[index] for index in GI]

    return GV
```

Once I try "list of list", I cannot get the similar results. My code looks like below so far:

```
NN = [['name 1', 'name 2','name 3'], ['name 1', 'name 2','name 3'], ['name 1', 'name 2','name 3'], ['name 1', 'name 2','name 3'], ['name 1', 'name 2','name 3'], ['name 1', 'name 2','name 3']]

VV = [['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3'], ['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3'], ['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3'], ['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3'], ['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3']]


def GV(NN,VV,name):
    bool_ls = []
    NNN = NN
    for j in NNN:
        for i in j:
            if i == name:
                i = 'y'
            else:
                i = 'n'
            bool_ls.append(i) 

# here is where I'm lost
```

Help greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Why aren't you using `zip`?

Comment: Also, FYI: `NNN = NN` does _**not_** make a copy of `NN`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - but if I use deepcopy is changing my results, so I used newlist = oldlist

Answer (score 2):

You can generate pair-wise combinations from both list using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and then *filter* in a list comprehension.

For the flat lists:

```
def GV(N, V, name):
    return [j for i, j in zip(N, V) if i==name]
```

For the nested lists, you'll add an extra nesting:

```
def GV(NN,VV,name):
    return [j for tup in zip(NN, VV) for i, j in zip(*tup) if i==name]
```

In case you want a list of lists, you can move the nesting into new lists inside the parent comprehension.

Comment: thank you - I'm testing your solution and report back. (I got lost on my logic trying to use .zip)

Comment: If this is for python2, then it will become unwieldy for large volumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do what your function is doing, but, to answer your question, you just need two loops (one for each level of lists): the first list iterates over the list of lists, the second iterates over the inner lists and does the somewhat odd `y` or `n` thing to chose a value.

Comment: "There's an easier way to do what your function is doing"  thank you. I'm here to learn, if you can suggest what the method is will be great. thanks.